# I run cURL command using API key and extract data in test1.json file and then I use python 2.7 using json module to parse

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, shell, curl

I execute curl command using API and get data in test1.json file

then I use below python script to parse that data so that data using json module
I get in 1 line with slash n starting and ending the all key and value

```
import os
import json
# test.sh is a curl command for getting customer id and then extract all 
data for all child customer and save the result to test1.json
os.system('sh test1.sh')

# Open test1.json file and read them 
with open('test1.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    d = json.dumps(data, indent=6)
    print(d)
```

Comment: whats the actual problem?

Comment: Explain your problem so that we can help you.

Comment: I am getting output in below format.

\"Microsoft\"\n{\n  \"syslog\": {\n    \"created\": {\n      \"at\": 1478551613,\n      \"by\": 0\n    },\n    \"id\": \"4AA94D2D-40BC-1005-8535-0050568525A9\",\n    \"metadata\": {\n      \"host_type\": \"standalone\",\n      \"local_ipv4\": [\n        \"10.10.10.10\"\n      ],\n      \"os_type\": \"unix\",\n      \"version\": \"1\",\n      \"local_hostname\": \"microsoft-log-01\",\n      \"local_ipv6\": [\n        \"fe50::214:66ff:fec0:8\",\n        \"ff20::baac:4fff:ff22:e214\"\n      ],\n      \"num_logical_processors\": 4,\n

Comment: I am expecting them in below format

{
    "Customer": Microsoft, 
    "metadat": [
        IP
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You're double-serialising your json (assuming `test1.json` contains json).

```
>>> with open('test1.json', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, f)
... 
>>> with open('test1.json', 'r') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)  # decode the json in the file
... 
>>> print data
{u'a': 1, u'b': 2}
>>> print json.dumps(data, indent=6)
{
      "a": 1, 
      "b": 2
}
>>>
```